# On definition of codimension of projective variety in $\mathbb{P}^{n-1}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request

I am getting confused with definition of codimension of projective variety in  $\mathbb{P}^{n-1}$. Since I couldn't find my answer by searching around the internet, I was hoping someone could possibly clarify if I have the correct idea.

Let $X \subseteq \mathbb{P}^{n-1}_{\mathbb{C}}$ be a projecive variety. 
Then is codimension of $X$:

($n - $ dim $X$) or $(n-1-$ dim $X)$?

Thank you very much!

Comment: It is the second formula.

Comment: Why do you call your ambient projective space $\mathbb P^{n-1}$ instead of  $\mathbb P^n$, as law-abiding citizens usually do ?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg I am not sure, it was just how it showed up when I was reading an article... my apologies for violating a law!

Comment: Nice answer, Johnny: you got humour!

Comment: lol. you too! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $X$ is a subvariety of a variety $Y$, then the *codimension* of $X$ in $Y$ is
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{codim}{codim}\codim_YX=\dim Y-\dim X
$$
Now, one may prove that $\dim \Bbb P^d=d$. Hence
$$
\codim_{\Bbb P^{n-1}}X=\dim\Bbb P^{n-1}-\dim X=n-1-\dim X
$$
That is, your second proposed equation is correct.